# how to make border line and table border line as equal way

Tags: html, css

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    @page {
            size:A4 portrait; 
            border-top:1.2px solid black;
            border-bottom:1.2px solid black;        
    }
    </style>
<style type="text/arial" media="print">    

            @page {
                margin: 75px 16px 75px 16px;
                @PageBreak{
                   page-break:always;
                    page-break-inside:avoid;
                } 

                @top-center {
                    content: element(header);
                }
                @bottom-center {
                    content: element(footer);
                }
            }             
            div.header{   
            position: running(header);           
            } 
            div.footer {
                position : running(footer) ;
            }

            .pagenumber:before {                
                content: counter(page);             
            }                       
            .pagecount:before {             
                content: counter(pages);            
            } 

        </style>             
    </head>
            <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-top:solid; border-color:#EBEBEB;">
                <tr>           
                    <td align="center">
                        <apex:outputText value="Page " style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;"/>
                        <span class="pagenumber" style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;"/> 
                        <apex:outputText value="of" style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px"/> 
                        <span class="pagecount" style="font-face:verdana;font-size:0.68em;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>         
            </table>
```

[image]

I cant able to equalize table border and top border .
either i am keeping the table width as 100% still it is no expanding 
I have no option to decrease the border to table width help me to find a solution

suggest me how to recover from this problem

Comment: try to reset cellspacing and cellpadding to 0, as well as table border to 0

Comment: @Aru table border has to be there

Comment: then what is that black border?? I hope you need to remove the top, left and right space!

Comment: can u post a fiddle of ur code? it'ld be easier for someone to help you?

Comment: Have you tried to set all paddings (cellpadding plus CSS-padding) to 0?

Answer (score 1):

instead you can use a class like the below:

**Html**

```
<div class="tabularcontent">
    <table width="100%" class="tablecontent">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
table {
    border-spacing:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.tabularcontent {
    border:2px solid black;
}
.tablecontent {
    border:2px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ayjrpk3/)

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css

```
table {
    border-spacing:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
}
th {
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ayjrpk3/2/)